# Synonym for cul-de-sac?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

Is there a synonym for *cul-de-sac*, perhaps one which does not sound French?

Comment: Google gives me[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cul-de-sac) as a first link, which mentions dead end (British, Canadian, American, South African English, and Australian English), closed, no through road (British, Canadian, and Australian English), no exit (New Zealand English) or court (Australian English). Are those too French-sounding?

Comment: I love the fact that a cul-de-sac in French is "une voie sans issue"

Comment: Tolkien offered Bag End in The Hobbit: see http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Bag_End

Comment: "Dead-End" may be the word you're looking for.

Comment: In the US it would be "Dead End", "No Outlet", "No Exit", "Road Ends", and a few others.  "Cul de Sac" would be ridiculed as being hoity-toity in most of the US.

Comment: @HotLicks [Cul-de-sac](https://www.google.com/maps/@38.8915327,-77.111027,74m/data=!3m1!1e3!5m1!1e4) (16th Pl N) vs. [dead end](https://www.google.com/maps/@38.8938609,-77.1307315,108m/data=!3m1!1e3!5m1!1e4) (21st St N) and the distinction has been well-understood everywhere I've lived, which is mostly not-so-hoity-toity places in the U.S.

Comment: @choster - Which is another point -- many people take "cul-de-sac" to mean a circular drive (or at least a drive with a circle at the end).

Answer (score 5):

Nope. That's why we use cul-de-sac. "Dead-End" doesn't quite fit the bill because, while all cul-de-sacs are dead-ends, not all dead-ends are cul-de-sacs. (US)

Comment: Surely there’s nothing wrong with Old Bag End, now is there, @OldBag? :)

Comment: _"The way is shut. It was made by those who are Dead, and the Dead keep it[...]"_?