# How and why have French words arrived in the English language?

Tags: history, french

I've just finished watching *Stranger Things*, and in one episode, Nancy mentions a *cul-de-sac*, which is essentially a French word (I'm French and we recognize when English uses French words, with this beautiful accent). And this made me think about **why** the English language uses French words, and whether there any equivalents for these words in English (*cul-de-sac, rendez-vous*, etc ...)?
A third [arguably] question is: at what point in history did these words begin to be used in English?

(Of course, the same questions for borrowings in the other direction may be asked, about English words now assimilated into the French language, but I believe this not to be a suitable topic for ELU.)

Thanks for any response :)

EDIT: Let's forget the third question, I didn't think it was that old.
So, my only question is: why does the English language use French words?

Comment: This is a really broad question, since a complete answer would discuss the Norman Conquest, the persistence of Anglo-Norman in medieval England, French as an early modern language of considerable status, the French influence on American and British political and military theory, the rise of French goods in English markets, and so on. If you limit your question to a single word or a single kind of vocabulary, this becomes more answerable.

Comment: They came by way of the English Channel. For the past thousand years whenever someone from France has wanted to cross over to the Isle of Britain, they must come bearing a French word on their tongue to be collected as toll for their passage by the ferryman. He later spends these  exotic new coinages in Dover pubs, whence they in due time come to spread to the rest of the realm from Land’s End to John o'Groats, as often as not in a tarnished condition made rather worse for the wear by the great many British bite marks probing their value.

Comment: You could start in [1066](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Hastings) and go on to this wikipedia article [Influence du français sur l'anglais](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Influence_du_fran%C3%A7ais_sur_l%27anglais). If not tons of books have been written on the question.

Comment: "the same questions for borrowings in the other direction may be asked, about English words now assimilated into French language":  Visit Stack Exchange [French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/) but such an open question would certainly qualify as too broad.

Comment: @tchrist Invaders are advised not to speak on both sides of the Channel at once.

Comment: Here's a thread addressing questions 1b and 2a (where 'a' refers to the case of  'cul-de-sac' {which is perhaps more English than French nowadays,  as it's the standard term here}): [synonymfor 'cul-de-sac'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225086/synonym-for-cul-de-sac).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth “Not in Bag End it’s not!” decried Bilbo.

Comment: @tchrist Un 'there-and-back-again'. But perhaps all French loanwords will have to be returned soon.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth [A cul-de-sac is presumably where English beat those Frenchmen unconscious to rifle their pockets for new vocabulary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Nicoll#%22The_Purity_of_the_English_Language%22). A few of them _have_ been returned — a modern Frenchman might be wearing *des tennis* (sports shoes, from French “*tenez*” (“here you are”), via the English sport *tennis*).

Comment: @Gilles Un tiens vaut mieux qu'un tu l'auras.

Comment: Presumably such words were borrowed because, at the time, they were felt to express a concept for which there wasn't a word in English, or to express an idea more elegantly than the existing word. For instance, we began to speak of _restaurants_ when we began to eat at a commercial establishment as a social experience rather than just because we needed a meal when away from home.

Comment: All languages have loans words. Are we going to write a treatise on every one of them here?? "Tenez" as in "'Here you go" when the ball was batted by a (noble) man in early tennis games. The English word for tennis comes from that.